# Import pip3 results in "ImportError: No module named 'pip3'

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I am on Windows 7 with Python 3.5 installed on it.
Below is what happens:
    import pip # works as expected
    import pip3 # results in below error

```
ImportError: No module named 'pip3'
```

- I have pip and pip3.exe both sitting in the same scripts folder.
- I have scripts folder, site packages and python folder all added to my environment variable path (I have added it in user profile, as I do not have admin access to add to system variables)

Is there any solution which you all have tried and worked. I am new to python and any help is appreciated.

Comment: pip and pip3 are tools to manage Python libraries. Why do you want to import it as a library in python code?

Comment: If you are running Python 3.x, `pip` **is** `pip3`. The `pip3` command-line tool is simply a shortcut for `python3 -m pip`.

Comment: So, is there no difference between pip and pip3? Like, for example, if I need to import beautifulsoup or any other related modules, would it allow or am I totally on different path?

Comment: If you are trying to import a module from a package like beautifulsoup, you need to use the `pip` that corresponds to the `python` your program will run with. You can have multiple Pythons installed at the same time, and each one can have a `pip` tool for installing more third-party packages into it. However, *your program* should not be installing its own third-party dependencies: you should create a `setup.py` to handle that.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thank you. I am running it on Python3.5.2 Shell. So, if it recognizes pip, I need not worry about pip3 or pip3.5 ?

Comment: I have only one version of python installed - Python3.5

Comment: Is "Python 3.5.2 Shell" a Windows thing? You typically don't execute pip from inside a Python interactive session ("repl"); pip adds new dependencies into your Python, so you launch pip from a standalone command line.

Comment: Basically: if your prompt looks like `>>>` then you (probably) shouldn't be trying to invoke `pip` from there.

Comment: @DanielPryden I tried it from the Windows commandline and the request is timing out.

Answer (score 0):

So, I learned that my problem with installing beautifulsoup was because of the firewall restriction in my organization, which I was relating to pip install.
I learned of the proxy settings and using that, got to install bs4 via the conda interpreter.

Thank you for all the answers, which made me think through on various aspects, which I would not have thought of without the probing questions brought up here.